# Split a vector in R depending on entries

Tags: r, vector, split

I input a vector `vec<-c(2  3  4  8 10 12 15 19 20 23 27 28 39 47 52 60 64 75)`, and the size of intervals that I want to break the vector entries into.

In this example I want to break this into 9 different vectors based on the size of each entry.
In my case I want vector number 1 to be entries in the interval [1,9], then vector 2 to be entries in [10,18]...ect

In other words:

```
vec1: 2 3 4 8
vec2: 10 12 15
vec3: 19 20 23 27
```

ect...

I have tried using the split function but I do not know how to set a ratio that will work.

Comment: *... based on the size of each entry* - what does that mean?  Please further explain how you get from `vec` to the output.

Comment: I'd suggest using integer division to figure out which vector each one belongs into `%/%` is the operator.

Comment: Sure, I would like to input a vector, and an interval size, and the output will be a number of vectors with entries in those increasing intervals. In the above example I chose intervals of [1,9], [10,18],...

Comment: @Gregor close, but your output doesn't match OPs. I think you want this `split(vec,vec %/%9)`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my question. @Mako212 that answer works nicely, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integer division `%/%` to return a vector of which group each value belongs in. Then `split` into separate vectors. Use `(vec-1)` to be "inclusive", i.e. 27 goes with group 3, not group 4.

```
split(vec,(vec-1) %/% 9)
```

Edit:

Another way using `dplyr` and `cut` which explicitly tags each interval

```
require(dplyr)

vec <- as.data.frame(vec)

df2 %>% mutate(interval = cut(vec,breaks=seq(0,((max(vec) %/% 9) +1) * 9,9),include.lowest=TRUE,right=TRUE))

   vec interval
1    2    [0,9]
2    3    [0,9]
3    4    [0,9]
4    8    [0,9]
5   10   (9,18]
6   12   (9,18]
7   15   (9,18]
8   19  (18,27]
9   20  (18,27]
10  23  (18,27]
11  27  (18,27]
```

Comment: I think it should be `split(vec,(vec -1)%/% 9)` as in my case I am starting my first interval at 1 rather than 0

Comment: @user7512228 Yes, fixed. I missed that it was "inclusive" on 27.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following will do what you want.

```
f <- cut(vec, seq(0, max(vec), by = 9), include.lowest = TRUE)
sp <- split(vec, f)
sp <- sp[sapply(sp, function(x) length(x) != 0)]
sp
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this

```
library(purrr)
vec <- c(2,  3,  4,  8, 10 ,12, 15 ,19, 20, 23, 27, 28, 39, 47, 52, 60, 64, 75)

vec1 <- keep(vec, function(x) x >= 1 & (x) <= 9)
vec2 <- keep(vec, function(x) x >= 10 & (x) <= 18)
```